# Http send() request doesn't return any values

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I want to know why my update doesn't populate local Sqlite database. Yesterday with few records in database application worked correctly. Today after inserting another 10 records. Both send method seem to work properly but they don't return data. It updates only IngredientDB but not RecipeID Request . This  is my update action script code,

```
 dishName.addEventListener("Success", dishName_resultHandler);
dishName.addEventListener("...", faultHandler);
dishName.send();
dishIngs.addEventListener("Success", ingredients_resultHandler);
dishIngs.addEventListener("...", faultHandler);
dishIngs.send();
protected function dishName_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
externalRecipes=event.result.recipes.recipe;
}

protected function ingredients_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
externalIngredients=event.result.ingredients.ingredient;
}
```

This is my php script for my first table

```
$mysql_host = "...";
$mysql_database = "...";
$mysql_user = "...";
$mysql_password = "....";

$conn = mysql_connect("...", "...","...") or      die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("....", $conn);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `RecipeDB`';
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('recipes');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$xml->startElement("recipe");

    $xml->writeElement('RecipeID', $row['RecipeID']);
    $xml->writeElement('Name', $row['Name']);
    $xml->writeElement('Category', $row['Category']);
    $xml->writeElement('Origin', $row['Origin']);
    $xml->writeElement('Recipe', $row['Recipe']);
    $xml->writeElement('Favorite', $row['Favorite']);
    $xml->writeElement('Image', base64_encode($row['Image']));



$xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

$xml->flush();
```

and similar for second

```
$conn = mysql_connect("...", "..","...") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("....", $conn);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `IngredientDB`';
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->writeRaw('<?xml version="1.0"?>');
$xml->startElement('ingredients');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$xml->startElement("ingredient");

    $xml->writeElement('rowid', $row['rowid']);
    $xml->writeElement('RecipeID', $row['RecipeID']);
    $xml->writeElement('Ingredient', $row['Ingredient']);
    $xml->writeElement('Quantity', $row['Quantity']);



$xml->endElement();
}
```

This is my calls to server

```
 <s:HTTPService id="dishName"
 url="http://.../dish.php"
 result="dishName_resultHandler(event)"
 fault="faultHandler(event)"/>

 <s:HTTPService id="dishIngs"
 url="http://.../Ingedient.php" 
 result="ingredients_resultHandler(event)"
 fault="faultHandler(event)"/>
```

This is structure of my database

```
CREATE TABLE `RecipeDB` (
`RecipeID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Name` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Category` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Origin` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Recipe` varchar(2000) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Favorite` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`Image` blob NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`RecipeID`)
)

CREATE TABLE `IngredientDB` (
`rowid` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`RecipeID` int(5) NOT NULL,
`Ingredient` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Quantity` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`)
)
```

Comment: so is it sqlite or mysql?  what does "doesn't return any values" exactly mean?

Comment: Your webhost seems to add google analytics code to the php output. Do you use the Flash content debugger plugin? Does it complain about malformed XML?

Comment: btw. you should _really_ remove the database details from your code samples...

Comment: the database is mysql. and doesn't return any values it means that doesn't assign any values to externalRecipes and externalIngredients arrayCollection(by the way they are both initialize beforehand) There are no errors displayed

Answer (score 0):

How do you have configured your webserver? Maybe it's a php error on your script and you're not getting an answer because the server (or mayeb php) is configure not to display errors.

Did you check your error log? You could also try executing the php file directly instead of doing it through Flash, just to be sure that the URL is right and that the answer is well-formed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: document xml is correctly formated, problem seems to be with copying values from xml file to ArrayCollection. Problem is either with Sending the xml resolt to diviace or copying values to ArrayColletion